# Python Nesting Modules

Tags: python, module, package

I have spent a lot of time researching this and still cannot understand why I keep getting ImportErrors: No module named ...

My file structure is as follows:

```
/Package
    /mode
        __init__.py
        moduletoimport.py
        /test
            __init__.py
            abc.py
```

File `moduletoimport.py` contains:

```
class ClassToImport(object):
    def test(self):
        return True
```

File `abc.py` contains the following code:

```
from mode.moduletoimport import ClassToImport
```

From the terminal I type:

```
python abc.py
```

The aim here is to import a module that is up the directory.

Comment: Is the `Package` directory on `sys.path`?

Comment: That seems like a very odd way to structure your project. Have a look at e.g. http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/

Comment: Thank you. Will re-think my project structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quick Fix

A quick fix to this problem is, in the file `abc.py` add the following to the top of the file:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..')))
```

**However, this is really not that correct.** I have some serious questions about the way you're structuring your project and believe the below section will help greatly.

### Better Solution

In general, if you're designing a module to be imported, you want your project structure to look something like this:

```
package_name/
  /* setup.py and other misc files */
  package_name/
    __init__.py
    /* module files go here */
  test/
    /* tests go here */
```

The top level `package_name/` is really just for holding the project. It will contain your `setup.py`, possibly configuration things etc.

Underneath the top level, we have another directory called `package_name`. This is where all your actual python code will go.

Also underneath the top level, we have another directory called `test`. This is where all the tests should go. I would strongly consider using [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to test your python application.

### Example

Let's build a quick example of what you are trying to accomplish. The final product will have the following structure/files:

```
my_project/
  my_project/
    __init__.py
    my_class.py
  test/
    test_my_class.py
```

The contents of `my_class.py` are:

```
class MyClass(object):

  def test(self):
    return True
```

The contents of `test_my_class.py` are:

```
import unittest
from my_project.my_class import MyClass

class TestMyClass(unittest.TestCase):

  def test_my_class(self):
    c = MyClass()
    self.assertEqual(c.test(), True)
```

Now, if you [install nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) you should be able to (from the top level of your project) run `nosetests`.

There are tons of tutorials out there for how to do this. But for brevity's sake, I'll let you do some searching on your own.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's great! I really appreciate you taking your time to answer the question with such detail! 
I will re-think my project structure!