# importing module from second module

Tags: python

I am developing small app with few submodules:

```
src/
    setup.py
    myapp/
        myGuiapp.py
        modules/
            __init__.py
            editorGui.py
            fileParser.py
```

modules/__ init __.py

```
from editorGui import editorWindow
from fileParser import parseMyFile
```

myGuiapp.py

```
from modules import editorWindow
from modules import parseMyFile
parseMyFile(parms)
editorWindow(self)
```

EditorGui.py

```
from fileParser import parseMyFile
# from .fileParser import parseMyFile
# from modules.fileParser import parseMyFile
fileParser(parms)
```

I would like to have my EditorGui.py to be called from myGuiapp.py but also to be able to run it by itself.
How should i setup relative importing in such case ?

If in EditorGui.py I will set :

```
from modules.fileParser import parseMyFile
>python editorGui.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules'
```

but from main app

```
>python myGuiapp.py
```

OK !

If in EditorGui.py I will set :

```
from .fileParser import parseMyFile
>python EditorGui.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.fileParser'; '__main__' is not a package
```

If in EditorGui.py I will set :

```
from fileParser import parseMyFile
>python editorGui.py
```

OK !

```
>python myGuiapp.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fileParser'
```

How can I make both work and what i am doing wrong here? I would like to avoid setting up ABSOLETE paths to this dev directory.
What would be most pythonic and clean way to structure such app ?

**EDIT:**
After @Diego Trazzi post, I've decided to move my EditorGui.py up the level:

```
src/
    setup.py
    myapp/
        myGuiapp.py
        editorGui.py
        modules/
            __init__.py
            fileParser.py
```

This solves many issues but for curiosity, my question still stands. How can I import module from same level while being imported by code from parent directory?

Comment: Use [python's `-m` option](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m).

Comment: it does not sound like pythonic way of cleaning up code. It's rather a workaround, similar to direct, absolete path to module.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid specifying the relative path to the modules You could append to your file the path:

```
# yourfile.py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/application/app/folder')
```

You could also specify it in the shell from which you run the command:

```
python [-bBdEiOQsRStuUvVWxX3?] [-c command | -m module-name | script | - ] [args]
```

https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html

#### Better solution

Ideally your project should be structured in such way so all the

```
package_name/
  /* setup.py and other misc files */
  package_name/
    __init__.py
    /* module files go here */
  test/
    /* tests go here */
```

So that your executables reside in the top level and when you distribute your project users will not have to dig into sub folders. I have found this answer very helpful:

[Python Nesting Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362570/python-nesting-modules)

Comment: Thanks Diego! I would really prefer to avoid adding any kind of paths to my code as it is not procedural way i would prefer to have. As for the structure, maybe you're right, maybe i should decide to move my EditorGui.py up  to be in the same level as main myGuiapp.py it may solve some issues.